# Bootstrap JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields & the rest form is not working as intended

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using the bootstrap version 4. Index.php includes the below contact form. I want users to see the validation messages when they click submit to draw their attention to the required fields they have missed. For example, when a user hits submit without filling any field, the user sees the below, which is the behavior I want to achieve, and I currently have:

[please note that to save space in this post, all images can be shown by clicking on *run code snippet*]

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1KwJ.png" width="50%" height="50%" />
```

The contact form: **Index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class ="container">

<div class="col-lg-6 push-lg-3">

<h1> Contact us</h1>
<p>Fill out the below form to contact us</p>

<form id="contactForm" class="contact-form needs-validation" action="form.php" method="POST" novalidate>
    <div class="contact-form-success alert alert-success d-none mt-4" id="contactSuccess">
        <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent to us.
    </div>

    <div class="contact-form-error alert alert-danger d-none mt-4" id="contactError">
        <strong>Error!</strong> There was an error sending your message.
        <span class="mail-error-message text-1 d-block" id="mailErrorMessage"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="name" class="required font-weight-bold text-dark">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label class="required font-weight-bold text-dark">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="font-weight-bold text-dark">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter the phone number." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="required font-weight-bold text-dark">Message</label>
            <textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Please enter your message." rows="5" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Your_Public_Key"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-modern" data-loading-text="Loading...">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/view.contact.js"></script>


<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          else {
            $("#submit-btn .text").text("Enviado");
            $("#submit-btn").addClass("active");
          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
</script>


<script>
$("#contactForm").validate();
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

**The issue**

I have the issue that when the user hits submits, everything goes as planned, and the form refreshes, and the success message appears, but the form refreshes with validation showing **red boxes**, which is the problem I want to solve. This is how a successful form submission currently looks like and this is incorrect:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV7A6.png" width="50%" height="50%" />
```

When the user hits submit, I want the user to see the success message; I want the form to refresh without green or red boxes to the input fields. To better understand this, please have a look at the below behavior I want to achieve:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yf01.png" width="50%" height="50%" />
```

I know that the issue is in the JavaScript for disabling form submissions (above) or in the view.contact.js:

I appreciate any insights or guidance about how I can fix this.

One more question I have is this: Will I need the below code?

```
<script>
$("#contactForm").validate();
</script>
```

Any comment on how to make this code better is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official documentacion:

> To reset the appearance of the form (for instance, in the case of
> dynamic form submissions using AJAX), remove the .was-validated class
> from the  again after submission.

[Bootstrap > Form > Validation > How it Works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#how-it-works)

In your case, you need to add the following line:

```
$form.removeClass('was-validated');
```

Inside:

```
$.ajax({...})
.done(function() {
    //HERE
),
.always({...});
```

Comment: Thanks! It should be in this format: `$('#formid').removeClass('was-validated') ` The `$('#formid')` should be there for this to work. In my case, I used `$('.contact-form').removeClass('was-validated')`

Comment: That's true, I removed the "." on removeClass in case anyone has the same doubt