# Bootstrap Validations: Best practices to use bootstrap validation and Jquery Validation: Is the below correct? Any recommendations?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a contact form ([index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67260293/bootstrap-javascript-for-disabling-form-submissions-if-there-are-invalid-fields/67260526?noredirect=1#comment118888985_67260526)) with bootstrap styles and at the end of the form, I want to use the following two validations:

 The first is [bootstrap validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#validation):

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          else {
            $("#submit-btn .text").text("Enviado");
            $("#submit-btn").addClass("active");
          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
</script>
```

The second is [Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/):

```
<script>
$("#contactForm").validate();
</script>
```

I want to disable the form submission if there are invalid fields, and I want the user to know the reason why the submission was not accepted. I also want to validate what the user enters. The questions are:
 
 Is there a specific order I have to follow to organize the below links? Is there any duplication in my validation? (i.e., Do I use two different ways to validate the same thing?).
 
 These all are questions I need your help to answer to make sure the code is correct. I highly appreciate your support!

```
<form> .... </form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/view.contact.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<script>
$("#contactForm").validate();
</script>


<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
// https://gist.github.com/wwwisie/faef68540a1e0decf37acd5cd5e98dfe
// https://designmodo.com/validate-forms-bootstrap/
(function () {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
</script>
```

Comment: Can you say about the second one? Is it a jquery validation plugin you have used?

Comment: Ok. To understand further your requirements can you edit the question with validation cases in your contact form? So that we can choose the best option for you

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question as you suggested!