# Javascript (jQuery) to show bootstrap success message (alert-success) after the contact form is submitted and for one time only

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have developed a contact form that redirects to a thank you page. The contact form is linked to `view.contact.js`, which resets the form, and shows a success message on the same page. That is fine, but the behavior that I want is to redirect the user to a thank you page that captures all the information the user has submitted and then destroy all the information if the user refreshes the page. I was able to achieve this using PHP sessions. I also used `view.contact.js` to redirect to the thank you page using: `self.location = 'thankyou.php';`

I am facing a problem with the green background of the bootstrap success alert. I want the success alert that contains the user message to appear one time only on the thank you page after the user is redirected and then destroyed if the user refreshes the page. If I use the below code on the thank you page, it will be shown as an empty green box after the session is destroyed:

```html
<div id="success_message" class="alert alert-success"></div>
```

Alternatively, I want to use the below code:

```html
<div id="success_message" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none"></div>
```

As you see, I used `display:none;`. I want to link the `thankyou.php` page to a Javascript that shows this box one time only when the form is submitted and redirected to the thank you. I want the green box to go away when the session is destroyed (i.e., when the user refreshes the page). So, what I am trying to achieve is to display the bootstrap success alert one time only. I added this script to the thank you page:

```
<script src="js/thankyou.js"></script>
```

This link contains this function:

```js
(function($) {
    'use strict';
$messageSuccess.trigger('#success_message').show();})
```

But that is not working. Any help from you is truly highly appreciated!

Note: I also tried to achieve this using PHP alone (see below) but I was unable to get the success alert:

```html
<div style="text-align:left; "><?php if(isset($_SESSION["name"])) {echo "<h1 class= 'alert alert-success;' role='alert;'>Thank you " . $_SESSION["name"] . "!</h1>"; }?> </div>
```

**Update**
To make the question clearer, have a look at this code [thanks to chris G contribution]:

```
<?php 
session_start();
 
/*
1st time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] doesn't exist => is set to true
2nd time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] is true => is set to false
3rd time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] is false
4th time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] is still false, etc.
*/
 
if (isset($_SESSION["thankyou"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) $_SESSION["thankyou"] = false;
}
else {
    $_SESSION["thankyou"] = true;
}
 
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Thank you!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <?php if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) echo "Thank you!"; ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you run this code for the first time, you will get Thank you! with a green alert-success background like the one below:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="023nwHr"><a href="https://imgur.com/023nwHr"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

If you run it for the second time (i.e., refresh the page), you will get a blank green background:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="CuQ1PsQ"><a href="https://imgur.com/CuQ1PsQ"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I want to hide the green background with the text to get a white background when the page is refreshed instead of having a blank green background. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Using `self.location = 'thankyou.php';` sounds like you're sending the form data via ajax, then redirecting in the success callback? Can you confirm this is what you're doing?

Comment: I'd say you need to check if the session storage key/value pair is not there (as you're destroying it in php, no?), then you should use `$messageSuccess.trigger('#success_message').hide();` to hide the green box.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve whatever you want to achieve? This looks pretty strange to me - can you reformulate your problem such that it is more precise?

Comment: @chris G - You are right. This is what I am doing!

Comment: Ok, so let's do this without JS then. Just send your form to `sendmail.php` instead, the regular way. In your sendmail script, send the email, then call `header("Location: thankyou.php");` This will remove the POST data. Now use a basic session variable to keep track of whether you have already displayed the green box. In thankyou.php, if the variable doesn't exist yet, set it to `true`. If it exists and is true, set it to `false`. Then echo the box if it is `true`.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Actually, the contact us form redirects to sendmail.php and I use Ajax. This is the code for the contact us form I use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67260293/bootstrap-javascript-for-disabling-form-submissions-if-there-are-invalid-fields

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, but it's kind of pointless unless you have to preprocess the form data (and even if you have to do that, you can still use a regular "pure HTML" submission). All you need is `<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">` and zero AJAX. Give it a try.

Comment: @Chris G, you are right! I have used `header("location: thankyou.php");` instead of `$arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');` to handle that as you recommended but I still don't know how I can show the success message for one time only on the thank you page. I noticed that if I use Ajax or the method which you recommended `(I like it!, thanks for the suggestion)` I still cannot achieve what I aspire to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you're sending form, I was just pointing out that using ajax is not necessary if you're using a primarily PHP based website. Anyway, here's how to show text the first time, then never again: https://pastebin.com/HPg6jVs1

Comment: I also just noticed that you can in fact use just this line: `$_SESSION["thankyou"] = !isset($_SESSION["thankyou"]);`

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! Thumbs up! I have done two edits to the code you have shared with me, the first is that I added bootstrap CSS to the HTML head. The second is that I added class to the code `<p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <?php if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) echo "Thank you!"; ?>
        </p>` After you refresh the page, you will still see the green alert. My original question, how can I get rid of that green alert on page refresh? :) Many thanks for your time and support! I highly appreciate that you gave me time to write this code. Stay safe