# Hide bootstrap success alert green background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4. I also use sessions to return a success message from the contact us form. On the first load, the user gets the intended message; on the second load (i.e., after the user refreshes the page), the message disappears as intended, but the green background success alert remains there. My question is: how can I get rid of that green alert on page refresh?

To simplify this, look at the below examples.

**Code example:**

```
<?php 
session_start();
 
/*
1st time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] doesn't exist => is set to true
2nd time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] is true => is set to false
3rd time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] is false
4th time: $_SESSION["thankyou"] is still false, etc.
*/
 
if (isset($_SESSION["thankyou"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) $_SESSION["thankyou"] = false;
}
else {
    $_SESSION["thankyou"] = true;
}
 
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Thank you!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <?php if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) echo "Thank you!"; ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Step 1:**

If you run this code for the first time, you will get Thank you! with a green alert-success background like the one below:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="023nwHr"><a href="https://imgur.com/023nwHr"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**Step 2:**

If you run it for the second time (i.e., refresh the page), you will get a blank green background:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="CuQ1PsQ"><a href="https://imgur.com/CuQ1PsQ"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I want to hide the blank green background when the page is refreshed (i.e., after the first load) and get a blank white background instead of having a blank green background. Any help is highly appreciated.

Note: This post is linked to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67417200/javascript-jquery-to-show-bootstrap-success-message-alert-success-after-the).

Comment: Why not just put the whole tag in your PHP if statement? `<?php if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) {?> <div class=''>Thanks</div> <?php } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand you correctly you want to show the message if the `$_SESSION["thankyou"]` asserts to `true`

if that's the case then you can wrap the:

```
<p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
     <?php if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) echo "Thank you!"; ?>
</p>
```

In an php if statement like this:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION["thankyou"])
{
?>
   <p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you!</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The green background comes from this element because of its `alert-success` class.

```
<p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <?php if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) echo "Thank you!"; ?>
</p>
```

If you don't want the green background, you would not include the `<p>` element in your response. In other words, try this:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION["thankyou"]) echo '<p class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you!</p>'; ?>
```

EDIT: Please go with @Total Newbie's answer. His/her version is cleaner and more scalable in general. And fixed quote escape.

Comment: you should escape your quotes, or this won't work